# How to delete everything below a certain point in a file.

Tags: python

I have a GFF3 file and at the bottom of the file there is a FASTA report of the genome. 
[I have attached an image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPlJG.gif)

I want to delete everything below the line that says '##FASTA' - including that line. 
I need to do this for multiple files. 
Please help.

Comment: your question could be good if 1) it included a text version of input & expected output, 2) an attempt. otherwise it's just personalized help, and SO isn't the site for that.

Comment: I can make it a text file. In the image you can see that - I want to delete everything below the line that says ##FASTA

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question to contain a sample of the data you are talking about. It isn't particularly a nice way to ask people for something. We don't need the whole file, just the important snippet as text.

The image is annoying for a multitude of reasons but what bothers me the most is that the imgur image could be removed for reasons beyond stackoverflow. Then your question becomes kind of useless.

---

You could do something like this:

```
# Read the file into a list
myfile = "path/to/file.fastq"
f = open(myfile,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# Reopen the file to write
f = open(myfile,"w")
FASTA=False
# Iterate over all the lines
for line in lines:
    # Set the flag if we reach the FASTA line
    if line == "##FASTA\n":
        FASTA = True
    # The FASTA flag causes the lines to be skipped
    if FASTA:
        continue/break
    # Write the line to the file
    f.write(line)

f.close()
```

If you can be sure that you don't need the rest of the file you could also `break` out of the loop instead of the `continue`. With continue it still goes through all the lines even after finding the `##FASTA` so thats good if you might find more usable data.